# Why planning scene can't subscribe the new planning scene?

Tags: c++, moveit, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone!
I am trying to add an object into RVIZ throught C++ interface.
I had follow the official tutorial [Planning Scene ROS API](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/planning_scene_ros_api/planning_scene_ros_api_tutorial.html) and failed in step 1....

My Code is follow

```
moveit_visual_tools::MoveItVisualTools visual_tool("world");
visual_tool.deleteAllMarkers();

ros::Publisher planning_scene_diff_publisher = node_hadle.advertise<moveit_msgs::PlanningScene>("planning_Scene",1);
ros::WallDuration sleep_t(0.5);

while (planning_scene_diff_publisher.getNumSubscribers() < 1)
{
  sleep_t.sleep();
}
visual_tool.prompt("Press 'next' in the RvizVisualToolsGui window to start the demo");
```

The fixed frame of my robot is "world".

The "Planning Scene Topic" shows in RVIZ is "/move_group/monitored_planning_scene".

After I run my code, I will see the can't break form `while (planning_scene_diff_publisher.getNumSubscribers() < 1)`.

In addition, rqt_graph shows nothing has subscribed from "planning_Scene" which I just creat.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/363186/why-planning-scene-can%27t-subscribe-the-new-planning-scene?/) by [Heho](https://answers.ros.org/users/52976/heho/) on ROS Answers with karma: 44 on 2020-10-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

TLDR: Make sure the topic name that your are publishing is actually the name being subscribed to.

If this follows the tutorial exactly, then you probably just need to map your topics correctly. It sounds like RVIZ is subscribing to `/move_group/monitored_planning_scene` and your topic is publishing to `planning_Scene`

In your launch file of this c++ node you can [remap the topic](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/remap) :

```
<remap from="planning_Scene" to="/move_group/monitored_planning_scene"/>
```

Or you can hardcode the RVIZ topic into the c++ node by replacing `planning_Scene` with `/move_group/monitored_planning_scene` where you define the publisher above.

---

Originally posted by [JackB](https://answers.ros.org/users/40162/jackb/) with karma: 977 on 2020-10-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1